# Termux can't run c++ programs?

Tags: android, c++, c, terminal, clang++

So I compiled a simple cpp program using clang++ with termux on android, but I can't run the program, I get the following error:

```
 $ ./execname
-bash: . /execname: Permission denied
```

Comment: did you tried to change privileges using `chmod` like `chmod 777 execname` before running program?

Comment: chmod:  execname:Operation not permitted

Comment: `su` to root, then you can chmod it.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I'm on Android

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you running on shared storage (under `/sdcard`)? The file system there does not support executable permissions.

Try compiling and running the file directly in the `$HOME` dir!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to give execution permission to your file, if not done already:

```
chmod +x execname
```

Also the shebang interpreter isn't working as expected in termux due to wrong systems paths, but there is a fix with the package [termux-exec](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-exec)

```
pkg install termux-exec
```

Comment: I moved the compiled program to internal storage and executed `chmod` command, and it worked, thank you.